# How to insert data from multiple tables to single table in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Below are my three source tables.

1. CAPTION **(Master Table)**
   COLUMNS:
   **CaptionId INT PK**
   CaptionText nvarchar(50)

Example Values:
Record #1: 1, Road Accident
Record #2: 2, Safety Criteria

2. BATCHDATES  **(Master Table)**
   COLUMNS:
   **BatchDateId INT PK**
   BatchDate DATETIME

Example Values:
Record #1: 1, 2019-01-31 00:00:00.000
Record #1: 2, 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000

**3. GENERATED SQL STATEMENT**
This one has sql statement with aggregated rows.

Hence, Above three are sources to read record and below one is where I am trying to write data.

4. FleetTable **(Destination Table)**
   COLUMNS:
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   **CaptionId INT,**
   **BatchDateId INT,**
   FleetType nvarchar(10),
   OperatingStatus nvarchar(25),
   FleetRange_1 numeric(10,3),
   FleetRange_2_4 numeric(10,3)

**NOTE**: Last 4 columns in above table are derived from SQL statement from point #3.

So far I have tried below using SSIS with no avail.

[image: Read three tables to fill one destination table]

Honestly, I cannot really share any code but an attached image above as I am intending to use SSIS.

As an expected result, I am intending to see output like below.

[image: Result of this task]

Some good insight from community is appreciated.

**MORE DESCRIPTION:**
In above point #3 **3. GENERATED SQL STATEMENT**, I am deriving a query which belongs to completely separate database and it has no reference to above master tables. And tables in first two points belong to separate database. Hence, I am not sure how lookup would help.

Comment: If i understood what you are looking for. Use lookups transformation instead of UNION and Merge

Comment: @Hadi, I have added more description. i thought about lookup earlier, but cannot clearly create relationship among 3 sources. OR can you share a little more detail how lookup could help.

Comment: @Binoy, are you able to write a single SQL statement (including the aggregation) from the data source for what you would like in the final output?

Comment: @Binoj then base on what you want to merge the rows?

Comment: @Hadi, I thought about Merge transform thinking that after doing Union (combining three source and I am doing correctly) merge would be an alternative to insert further. I am still investigating though.

Comment: @Leqid, No I cannot write single statement. As my query reads different database and other two master tables belong to different database.

Comment: @Hadi, After trying few things finally I sorted out my issue. And also your hint helped me. I had to tweak my database design a little to accommodate lookup transformation and everything went through.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the three point object name (i.e. DB.Schema.Table) and refer to objects in multiple databases in your single query.